# Polyline Error Line

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

Hi guys I have a Google Maps and the coordinates are pulled via parse XML data. This script was based on econym's site I am using V3 of Google Maps. Now the thing is I was able to display the markers right but the polyline isn't a single line instead it lines from one marker to another so it looks like a polygon which isn't supposed to happen.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var select_html = ""; 
      var gmarkers = []; 
      var map = null;

  function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
        var contentString = html;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
       });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        gmarkers.push(marker);

        return marker;
}

//function createPolyline

function initialize() { 

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude']?>, <?php echo $row['longitude']?>),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.close();

    });



  // Read the data from 100.xml

  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php?id=<?= $_GET['lgid']?>", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);

   path.push(marker.position);   
    }
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({     
                    path: path,     
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000"
    });    
    polyline.setMap(map);


  });
}



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(

  { 

    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)

  });
```

Would you mind taking a look? Thanks!

Comment: you have to use directions, if you want polyline should be on road...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where it was doing what you are talking about and it had to do completely with the fact that the waypoints were out of order.  In turn the route being displayed by the directionsRenderer was coming back across itself and not displaying at all like it should have been.  So, my suggestion is check the ordering of your waypoints.